# searching in listview in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, search

i am trying to search in listview but my string in search box is not reflecting in listview.I am getting the string in the console when I am printing it but listview is not reflected.Here is the code I wrote.I have fetched a nested json array and displayed it in a listview and want to perform search function on it.I new to flutter so not getting how to do this.

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: orange,
      title: Text('ATTENDENCE'),
    ),body:
      Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
      Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Container(
        color: skyblue,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 65,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20,left: 20,top: 10,bottom: 10),
        child:Row(
            children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                Text("Center Name",style: TextStyle(color: lightGrey,fontSize: 17)),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5),
                  child:Text(widget.centernametext.toUpperCase(),style: TextStyle(color: 
                  Colors.black,fontSize: 13)),
                ),

              ],)

            ),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                  child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Batch",style: TextStyle(color: lightGrey,fontSize: 17),textAlign: 
                    TextAlign.left,),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5),
                      child:Text(widget.batchname,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 13)),),
                  ],)
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                  child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Date",style: TextStyle(color: lightGrey,fontSize: 17)),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5),
                      child:Text(widget.date,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 13)),
                    ),

                  ],)

              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
     _searchBar(),
          Container(
              color: skyblue,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:170),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20,left: 20,top: 10,bottom: 10),
              child:Row(

                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Checkbox(
                    value: checkVal,

                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                  checkVal = value;
                  if(checkVal==true){
                    isSelected=true;
                  }else{
                    isSelected=false;
                  }
                  });
    }  ),
                  ),
                  Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5),
                      child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Name",style: TextStyle(color: lightGrey,fontSize: 17)),
                      ],)

                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5),
                      child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Age",style: TextStyle(color: lightGrey,fontSize: 17),textAlign: 
                       TextAlign.left,),

                      ],)

                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5),
                      child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Level no.",style: TextStyle(color: lightGrey,fontSize: 17)),

                      ],)

                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5),
                      child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Attend",style: TextStyle(color: lightGrey,fontSize: 17)),

                      ],)

                  ),
                ],
              )
          ),
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:230),

              child: ListView.builder(
                  //addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                  itemCount: filteredlist==null?0:filteredlist.length,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return new CustomWidget(
                    selected:isSelected,
                    rest:filteredlist,
                    index: index,
                    longPressEnabled: longPressFlag,
                    callback: () {
                      if (indexList.contains(index)) {
                        indexList.remove(index);
                      } else {
                        indexList.add(index);
                      }

                      longPress();
                    },
                  );

                  })

      )])));

  }


  _searchBar() {

    return Container(
        child:Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[

            Container(
                width: 250,
                height: 40,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,top:90),
                child:TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                      prefixIcon: new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only( top: 13, left: 0, right: 5, bottom: 13),
                        child: new SizedBox(
                          height: 2,

                          child: Image.asset('assets/search.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      labelText: "Search by name",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: lightGrey,
                          fontSize: 15
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder( borderSide: BorderSide(color: lightGrey, width: 0.5),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: orange, width: 0.5),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                      )),
                  controller: controller,
                  onChanged: (string){setState(() {
                    //print("log");
                    for (i = 0; i < rest.length; i++) {

                      if(rest[i]['student']['name'].contains(string)){
                        print(string);
                        print(i);

                      }

                    }
                    filteredlist.add(filteredlist[i]['student']['name']);
                    print(filteredlist);
                    filteredlist =  rest
                        .where((u) => (
                        (u[i]['student']['name']).toString().toLowerCase().contains(string.toLowerCase())
                    )).toList();

                    }
                    );

                  },

                )
            ),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,top: 85),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: 
                  blue),borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  minWidth: 100,
                  height: 40,
                  // set minWidth to maxFinite
                  color: blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                  },
                  child: Text("Search",style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),),
                )
            )
          ],
        )

    );
  }

  Future<List<Autogenerated>> StudentListRequest() async {
    String as=widget.accesstoken.toString();

    var url = 'http://demo.neurapses.com:3032/students? 
    center=5ca5ba30e0adb9c1839aa0d2&batch=5ca5c81597f8a03368df072c';

    var response = await http.get(url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $as'

      },

    );
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    } else {
      setState(() {
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        rest = data['docs'];

        for(var rest in rest)
        {
          list.add(Autogenerated.fromJson(rest));

        }

          filteredlist=rest;

      });

      return list;
    }


  }

  getStringValuesSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    str_accesstoken = prefs.getString('accesstoken');

  }
}


class Autogenerated {
  List<Docs> docs;
  Autogenerated(
      {this.docs,
        });

  Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['docs'] != null) {
      docs = new List<Docs>();
      json['docs'].forEach((v) {
        docs.add(new Docs.fromJson(v));
      });
    }

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.docs != null) {
      data['docs'] = this.docs.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Docs {
  Student student;
  Docs(
      {
        this.student,
        });

  Docs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    student =
    json['student'] != null ? new Student.fromJson(json['student']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.student != null) {
      data['student'] = this.student.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Student {
   String name;
   Student(
      {
        this.name,
        });

  Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
      return data;
  }

}

class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final bool longPressEnabled;
  final VoidCallback callback;
  final List rest;
   bool selected;
   CustomWidget({Key key, this.selected, this.rest, this.index, this.longPressEnabled, this.callback}) : 
   super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomWidgetState createState() => new _CustomWidgetState();

}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  final skyblue=Color(0xffF1F5F9);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
        margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        color: widget.selected ? Colors.grey[300]:Colors.white,
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              widget.selected = !widget.selected;
            });
          },
          value: widget.selected,
      title:
      Container(
      // color: mycolor,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
        Container(
        child: Text(widget.rest[widget.index]['student']['name'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors
          .black, fontSize: 15),)
    ),
    Spacer(),
    Container(
    child: Text("", style: TextStyle(color: Colors
        .black, fontSize: 15),)
    ),
    Spacer(),
    Container(
    child: Text(
    "", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 15),)
    ),
    Spacer(),
    Container(
    child: Text("", style: TextStyle(color: Colors
        .black, fontSize: 15),)
    ),
    ],
    ),
    ),

    ));

      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your rest list has data,

```
onChanged: (stringToSearch){
      filteredList = rest.where((f){
         var dataName = f['student']['name'].toString().toLowerCase();
         return dataName.contains(textToSearch);
      });
    }
```

no need to loop

Comment: It is working but now I am searching a text in listview and selecting that row of text in listview and when I am clearing the search textfield then that selected row is getting unselected.

Answer (score 0):

Add listener to your search TextField controller and generate new list of filteredList accordingly and then use

```
setState(() {
   currentList = newFilteredList;
});
```

to set new filtered list and re-build the whole widget.